# Prevent thousand separator in TSQL export to CSV

Tags: t-sql, csv, export

When exporting a TSQL select result to CSV the values show a strange thousandseparator. Partial code is:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),i.UserNumber_04) as CAP
```

The query results show perfect values, for example: 1470.00 but the CSV or txt file show strange values like 1,470,00. How can I prevent the first comma? 
At first I thought it was just the formatting style in excel, but it does the same in txt files.

Comment: How are u exporting the TSQL select result?

Comment: using batch file and sql command

Comment: It must be the batch file then causing the comma, can you share the batch file code?

Comment: I kind of solved it by casting it to nvarchar after casting it to a decimal first. Not the cleanest solution but it did the job.